What is the correct way of deploying .NET Core app to Ubuntu VPS?
I am trying to deploy my .NET Core application to an Ubuntu VPS. I have a GitHub Actions workflow with the following YAML configuration:
steps:
- name: Checkout code
  uses: actions/checkout@v4

- name: Set up .NET
  uses: actions/setup-dotnet@v4
  with:
    dotnet-version: '8.0.x'

- name: Restore dependencies
  run: dotnet restore

- name: Build
  run: dotnet build --configuration Release --no-restore

- name: Publish
  run: dotnet publish --configuration Release --no-build --output ./publish

- name: Deploy to Server using rsync
  uses: burnett01/rsync-deployments@7.0.1
  with:
    switches: -avzr --delete --exclude="" --include="" --filter=""
    path: ./publish/
    remote_path: /var/www/meal_prep/
    remote_host: ${{ secrets.HOST }}
    remote_user: ${{ secrets.USERNAME }}
    remote_key: ${{ secrets.SSH_PRIVATE_KEY }}

- name: Restart Service
  uses: appleboy/ssh-action@master
  with:
    host: ${{ secrets.HOST }}
    username: ${{ secrets.USERNAME }}
    key: ${{ secrets.SSH_PRIVATE_KEY }}
    script: |
      echo "${{ secrets.SUDO_PASSWORD }}" | sudo -S systemctl restart meal_prep

However, I am getting an error when running the "Deploy to Server using rsync" step:
sending incremental file list
rsync: [generator] delete_file: unlink(publish/YamlPrompt/MealPrepPrompt.txt) failed: Permission denied (13)
cannot delete non-empty directory: publish/YamlPrompt
rsync: [generator] delete_file: rmdir(publish/YamlPrompt) failed: Permission denied (13)

I had previously tried this configuration:
- name: Deploy to Server using rsync
  uses: appleboy/ssh-action@master
  with:
    host: ${{ secrets.HOST }}
    username: ${{ secrets.USERNAME }}
    key: ${{ secrets.SSH_PRIVATE_KEY }}
    script: |
      $publishFolder = "${{ github.workspace }}/publish"
      rsync -avz --delete $publishFolder ${{ secrets.USERNAME }}@${{ secrets.HOST }}:/var/www/meal_prep/

This was successful initially, but it didn't update the files on subsequent runs. Every time I made changes and tried to deploy, no changes were reflected. I had to manually remove the folder for it to create and update the files.
Can someone guide me on the correct way to deploy my .NET Core application using GitHub Actions?

Have you registered the public and private SSH keys correctly? Because the error message says it's 'permission denied'. The second thing is I think you better do as follows:

Stop the service.
Copy the files to your VPS.
Start the service again.

I saw you restart the service without stoping it first.
